# NUnit .NET create tests

Tags: c#, .net, nunit

I am working with teamcity and and moving some old integration tests over to it. These old integration tests just logged the results as a console application. I would stay with just logging the results but, teamcity has nice support for NUnit and would like to take advantage of it.

Lets say this was one of my old tests

```
    public void Test ()
    {
        int tries = 10;
        int fails = Check(tries);

        Console.WriteLine("{0} fails out of {1} attempts", fails, tries); // log results
    }

    public int Check (int tries)
    {
        int fails = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++)
        {
            if (i % 2 == 1) fails++;
        }
        return fails;
    }
```

I am not sure how to do this with NUnit or if it's even possible. I want each call of `Check` to be it's own test. And no, blocking out 10 tests to call `Check (n)` n = 0, ... n = 9 is not what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make use of NUnit's [data-driven tests](http://www.clear-lines.com/blog/post/Data-driven-tests-with-NUnit-25.aspx).

```
 [TestCase(10, Result = 5)]
 public int Check (int tries)
    {
    int fails = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++)
    {
        if (i % 2 == 1) fails++;
    }
    return fails;
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up going with the range attribute

```
[Test]
public int Check ([Range(0,100,1)] int tries)
{
   for (int i = 0; i < tries; i++)
   {
       if (i % 2 == 1) Assert.Fail("failed on :" + i);
   }
}
```